# Get apparent type of NewExpression using ts-morph

Tags: typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

I am currently trying to get the type of such declarations:

```
const x = new BehaviourSubject<string>(); // Should be of type BehaviourSubject<string>
```

Using ts-morph i tried:

```
const declX = sourceFile.getVariableDeclarationOrThrow("x");
declX.getType().getText();
declX.getApparentType().getText();
```

but in both cases i just get `any` as type. I suspect that i need to evaluate the NewExpression in some form using the ts-typechecker but can not find any references on how to do this.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Try checking `project.getPreEmitDiagnostics()`. When types go to `any` that means likely something is not setup correctly.

Comment: That was a good hint, thanks! I had a faulty configuration in my tsconfig file which i could sort out using the diagnostics output.